# Visualizing a set of 3D data points with a 2D plot

Tags: plotting

#### Orignal question

I am bit puzzled with the behaviour of `CountourListPlot` with my data. I have the following set of data:

```
data2 = {{0.90090, 0, 306.98}, {0.900914, 0.1, 306.93}, {0.90095, 0.2,
 306.80}, {0.90102, 0.3, 306.56}, {0.901122, 0.4, 
306.24}, {0.90124, 0.5, 305.83}, {0.901401, 0.6, 
305.32}, {0.901582, 0.7, 304.718}, {0.901792, 0.8, 
304.02}, {0.9020, 0.9, 303.22}, {0.9022, 1., 302.34}};
```

Then, it won't plot with the basic function

```
ListContourPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, DataRange -> Automatic]
```

but only when setting `DataRange -> All`. The problem is that then, my xy- coordinates are changed. I know that I can manually set `DataRange` to something like `DataRange -> {{0.9009, 0.902}, {0, 1}}`, but it is a bit like cheating since then the information I have in `{x, y}` is lost.

Evidently, I do not understand how this function works. Someone who can help me?

#### Updated question  [by m_goldberg]

I wrote an answer pointing out that `CountourListPlot` is not suited to this problem. The OP then made this comment:

> Thanks. It is true, you are right. However, a better way to visualize it in 2D would be to give each point a color code proportional to the zi value. Any idea how to do this?

That is really a rather different question than the original, so I am making this edit to make the revised the question available for answering.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your data is really suited to plotting with `ListContourPlot`. It is essentially points along a space curve. I believe it is better visualized with `ListPointPlot3D` or even the lower level function `Graphics3D`.

```
data =
  {{0.90090, 0, 306.98}, {0.900914, 0.1, 306.93}, {0.90095, 0.2, 
    306.80}, {0.90102, 0.3, 306.56}, {0.901122, 0.4, 
    306.24}, {0.90124, 0.5, 305.83}, {0.901401, 0.6, 
    305.32}, {0.901582, 0.7, 304.718}, {0.901792, 0.8, 
    304.02}, {0.9020, 0.9, 303.22}, {0.9022, 1., 302.34}};

ListPointPlot3D[data, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: pt_plot]

```
Graphics3D[Line[data], Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: graphics]

#### Update

Here is one way to make a 2D plot that preserves all the 3D data and color codes the z-coordinate. Tooltips are used to expose the 3D data to the viewer.

```
colors = Table[Blend[{Red, Darker[Green, .2]}, u], {u, data[[All, 3]] // Rescale}];
plotData = 
  MapIndexed[{{Extract[colors, #2], Point[#1[[{1, 2}]]]}, #1} &, data]

Graphics[
  {AbsolutePointSize[15], Tooltip @@@ plotData}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot2D]

Notes

- `colors` produces a coding of the z-coordinates of data as a blend of colors going from red to green as z goes from low to high.
- `plotData` remaps the raw data into 2D points of the appropriate color and appends the full 3D point to be displayed by `Tooltip`.

Comment: Thanks. It is true, you are right. However, a better way to visualize it in 2D would be to give each point a color code proportional to the zi value. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little awkward, but you can specify the data range directly:

```
d1 = data2[[All, 1]];
d2 = data2[[All, 2]]; 
ListContourPlot[data2, DataRange -> {{Min[d1], Max[d1]}, {Min[d2], Max[d2]}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`BubbleChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html):

```
BubbleChart[data2, ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[#3, 0, 0] &)]
```

[image]